# Generics with operators C#

Tags: c#, generics, operators

I need to use a generic method that subtracts the two operands, like this, with some pseudo coding.

```
public double GetResult<T>(T Arg1, T Arg2) : where T contains "-" operator
{
     return Arg1 - Arg2;
     //No, they are not value types, they are classes implementing the "-" operator
     //And eventually, they can be value types
}
```

Is that possible? Like there is a `where T = new()` for types with creators, is there a `where T contains "-" operator`?

Comment: No, it's not possible to write such a constraint in C#.

Answer (score 2):

The library at http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/ contains classes for performing math operations on generic arguments.

Comment: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html